# Как сравнить две даты на выявление более поздней или более ранней?

Tags: python

Всем привет и спрошедшими! Скажите, есть ли более вменяемый способ сравнения двух дат, нежели сравнение их в цикле: сначала годы, месяци, дни, часы и т.д.?

Comment: Странный вопрос. В python даты прекрасно сравниваются с помощью операторов < >. Уточните вопрос, если я вас не так понял.

Comment: То есть как это "сравниваются с помощью операторов < >"??? Я получаю время последнего изменения в дух файлах с помощью os.stat. Мне нужно сравнить, какой файл был изменен раньше или позже.

Comment: Такие вещи нужно уточнять в вопросе.

В документации сказано что st_mtime может зависеть от используемой ОС. Насколько я могу судить, оно возвращает дату в формате Unix timestamp, то есть это количество секунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 года. Какое число будет больше - та дата и новее.

Но я не могу понять, о каких годах, днях и часах идет речь в вопросе.

Comment: Ну, вот, к примеру:

    import time  
  
    t1 = os.stat("/home/zavulon/Programming/Projects/Python/FilesInspector/loadplugin.py").st_mtime
    print time.strftime("%d:%m:%y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(t1))
  
    27.12.14 09:07:47

Comment: Тип float, что-то типа 12409383.43
То есть как это она мне может врать? В общем, спасибо, сейчас буду колоть сыворотку правды :) А как отметить ваш ответ, как удовлетворительный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сравнивать голый результат.
Если он неоднозначный, то вам стоит выяснить, почему он такой. Вам может врать OS. Проверьте тип возвращаемого результата.

Любые преобразования к датам бессмысленны. Эти функции будут оперировать теми же данными, что и оператор больше-меньше. Это всего лиш количество секунд, прошедшее с 1970 года.

Единственное, если вам понадобится выполнять с датами какие-либо действия, сложнее сравнения, преобразуйте их в питоновский формат хранения даты и времени.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(st_mtime)
```

Его также можно сравнить простым `< >`.

Comment: не следует использовать `fromtimestamp()`, если нам известно `st_mtime` значение, так как локальное время не является линейным или монотонным или однозначным (из-за перевода часов, например, в нашей (Europe/Moscow) временной зоне 2010-2015 особенно примечательны). Лучше сравнивать `st_mtime` напрямую или в UTC преобразовывать `utc_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(st_mtime)`

Answer (score 3):

Даты в Питоне можно сравнивать напрямую: `now > then`.

Но перед сравнением необходимо убедиться, что они представляют один и тот же тип. Питон 2 не ругается, если несовместимые типы используются, например: `1 < "a"`; поэтому нужно самостоятельно следить к какому типу относятся переменные -- не следует сравнивать напрямую дату, выраженную как число с плавающей точкой (`float`) и  дату, сохранённую в строке (`str`). В Питоне 3 это поправлено и подобные сравнения вызывают `TypeError`.

В частности, если `t1` равен `os.stat(path).st_mtime`, то это так называемое "число секунд с эпохи" -- значение, возвращаемое `time.time()` функцией. Как правило, это число совпадает с POSIX временем -- "число секунд с Эпохи" (число SI секунд с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` (Эпоха), *исключая високосные секунды* -- иначе говоря число UT1 секунд (секунды, измеряемые вращением Земли (средне-солнечное время)). UTC время поддерживается +/- 0.9 секунд от UT1 времени c помощью високосных секунд.

Если `t1 > t2` это значит, что `t1` находится в будущем по отношению к `t2`, если `t2` также является "seconds since the epoch" значением.

`12409383.43` слишком маленькое число для POSIX timestamp -- оно указывает на 1970 год.